# Engine misfires in drive at a stop but not in park

Tags: toyota, camry, misfire

Why would my 4-cylinder 1999 Toyota Camry misfire in drive but not in park at a stop? It is not a constant skip just sometimes in drive. It is not getting worse maybe very very gradually. I am sure there are many reasons why an engine would skip but I am looking for the answer that is unique to this occasional misfire in drive but not in neutral in an otherwise good running engine?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "skips"? Doe you mean it develops a miss (as in misfire)? Could you also please give us information about your vehicle? Year/make/model/specific engine, etc. How much mileage?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 better?

Comment: Are there any codes present? Is the check engine light on?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 never